# Real solutions of third and fourth degree equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, polynomials

A few hours ago I "discovered" that if a third or fourth degree equation has distinct real solutions, it's possible to calculate them avoiding complex numbers.

In particular, we have:

```
poly = (x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3);
{c, b, a} = CoefficientList[poly, x][[1 ;; 3]];
d = a^2/3 - b;
e = 2 a^3/27 - a b/3 + c;
f = ArcCos[-3 Sqrt[3] e/(2 d Sqrt[d])];
N[{-a/3 + 2 Sqrt[3 d] Cos[(f - 4 Pi)/3]/3,
   -a/3 + 2 Sqrt[3 d] Cos[(f - 2 Pi)/3]/3,
   -a/3 + 2 Sqrt[3 d] Cos[(f - 0 Pi)/3]/3}]
```

> {1., 2., 3.}

```
poly = (x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4);
{d, c, b, a} = CoefficientList[poly, x][[1 ;; 4]];
e = 3 a^2/4 - 2 b;
f = 2 c - a b + a^3/4;
g = b^2 + 12 d - 3 a c;
h = 27 a^2 d - 9 a b c + 2 b^3 - 72 b d + 27 c^2;
i = ArcCos[h/(2 g Sqrt[g])];
j = (e + 2 Sqrt[g] Cos[i/3])/3;
N[{-a/4 - (Sqrt[j] + Sqrt[e - j + f/Sqrt[j]])/2,
   -a/4 - (Sqrt[j] - Sqrt[e - j + f/Sqrt[j]])/2,
   -a/4 + (Sqrt[j] - Sqrt[e - j - f/Sqrt[j]])/2,
   -a/4 + (Sqrt[j] + Sqrt[e - j - f/Sqrt[j]])/2}]
```

> {1., 2., 3., 4.}

After a few moments of joy, however, I noticed that, for example, if I write `(x - 10^-15)` instead of `(x - 1)`, I get respectively `6.66134*10^-16` and `8.88178*10^-16` instead of `10^-15` as the solution.

I intuitively believe that it's a numerical problem and that the main cause is `ArcCos`, but I'm not too sure and also I'm not able to establish if something can be done to solve the issue, or if I have to give up and I must necessarily rely on it to the good *Newton method*.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using arbitrary precision for `N`: `N[{your, expressions}, $MacinePrecision]`. On most machines `$MachinePrecision` is a little less than 16. If that's not enough, try requesting an even higher number of  digits of precision.

Comment: It might be cancelation error even if the arccos is quite accurate.

Comment: Try feeding your expressions to [Herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org/); it will try to rewrite them to minimize floating-point error. Not sure if it's going to do you any good, but you could use MMA to check if there is a difference in the numerical behavior at machine precision (which would correspond to Excel results) vs. the "true" value obtained with arbitrary precision.

Comment: The classical Cardano-type formulae are well-known to have poor numerical properties in general. There are reformulations in the literature you might want to look for, but in general, you should now understand why using `Root[]` in *Mathematica* is often numerically preferred.